# Under what conditions can a non-resonant satellite stay hidden from an observer on the ground?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, observation

From the perspective of someone on the ground, a satellite is usually not above the horizon all the time. But can a satellite have such an orbit that it is *never* above the horizon?

Such orbits clearly exist. The easiest example is a satellite in geostationary orbit, which will never be visible from the antipode of the stationary foot point.

However, geostationary and geosynchronous orbits are [resonant](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18066/are-there-terms-for-earth-orbits-with-rational-number-multiples-of-1-sidereal-da) orbits with an orbital period with a 1:1 resonance to the rotation of the Earth. In the grand scheme of things, such simple fractions are a special case.

**Theoretical motivation**: Orbital resonance requires the orbital period to be some rational numbers. The rational numbers form a countable set, while the real numbers do not, so "almost all" orbits are non-resonant.
**Practical motivation**: Satellites are subject to various perturbations, requiring active station keeping to stay in a resonant orbit.

An alternate and equivalent formulation is to find orbits such that a satellite can be located *anywhere* in it and still stay below the horizon all the time.

What are the constraints of such orbits?

Comment: While it's convenient to think of these as resonant, we shouldn't, unless you really mean that there is a regular exchange of energy "locking" their motion. [Is Dawn's upcoming low periapsis orbit for XMO7 “resonant”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27610/12102) Do you mean instead [repeat-ground track orbits](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18079/12102)? Resonance is "a thing" in physics and only happens in coupled dynamical systems, and I don't think that is what you are after here.

Comment: Maybe "rational-fractional-synchronous ground track orbits"? hmm.. maybe not ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a case of an answer originating before a question. Originally a spin-off problem from [this question asking about satellite footprints](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48531/is-it-possible-to-predict-if-an-orbiting-satellite-will-pass-over-a-given-point), it doesn't fit very well as an answer there. Hence this separate question and answer.

As it turns out, this has a straightforward geometric solution from observer latitude $\phi$ and inclination $i$:

$$r_P < \frac{r_{earth}}{\cos(\phi - i)}$$

$$r_A < \frac{r_{earth}}{\cos(\phi + i)}$$

From which a few corollaries follow:

- $i < \phi$
- $r_A$ is unbounded iff $i + \phi \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$
- $r_P$ is only unbounded iff $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $i = 0$
- There are no such orbits iff $\phi = 0$

Some practical consequences:

- For a hidden non-resonant orbit to have a perigee altitude above 200km, the observer must have a latitude greater than 14 degrees.
- The Moon is visible from the poles.

[image: non-resonant orbital constraints]

Alternate view, showing the tight squeeze when the observer is at low latitude:

[image: low altitude non-resonant orbit]

Alternate view, showing the degenerate polar case with unbounded apogee:

[image: degenerate polar non-resonant orbit]

Comment: This is a really nice answer!

Comment: perhaps this would have been better starting with the (hopefully) verily easily understood "something in equatorial orbit will never be visible from the poles" , and working outward from there?